# SED replace url string

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace a string which is currently output as

```
http://domain1.com/subfolder1/http://domain2.com/subfolder2
```

so that it will only output as

```
http://domain2.com/subfolder2
```

I am using SED to replace a URL with the latter domain but I'm unable to get it to work. It works if I set "domain1" to be replaced by "domain2" however I want to be able to replace the whole string.

I'm trying to do this will the following code:

```
for FILE in `cat/WORKDIR/$inputControlFileName`; do sed -i -e  "s~$SEARCHTEXT~$REPLACEWITH~g" $OutputDirectory/$FILE; done;
```

My search parameter is `http://domain1.com/subdomain/http://domain2.com/subdomain` and replace parameter is `http://domain2.com/subdomain`

Appreciate any guidance.

> Update
>   Thanks you all for your help, I ended up getting this to work by only outputting domain1.com/domain.2.com and then escaping the values stored in the variables.

Comment: why don't we truncate the first domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
echo "http://domain1.com/subfolder1/http://domain2.com/subfolder2" | sed 's/^http.*http:/http:/'
http://domain2.com/subfolder2
```

Comment: But what if the URL contains `http` as a subfolder name?

Comment: good catch....  hope we can overcome by suffixing second http with colon

Comment: Seems right. Something like `| sed 's/^http:\/\/.*http\:\//http:\/\//g'` would do the trick. I can also suggest `awk`: `| awk -F'http://' '{print "http://" $NF}'`

Answer (score 0):

If you **never** have **:** in the URI, you can do this only using bash builtins.

```
function last_addr(){
    IFS=: 
    string="$1"
    array=($string)
    echo -n http:; echo ${array[-1]}; unset IFS
}

last_addr 'http://domain1.com/subfolder1/http://domain2.com/subfolder2'
```

Comment: Thanks,  your comment about never having : gave me the solution.